# How to Find center of circle from QR decomposition

Tags: matlab, least-squares, qr-decomposition

I have to find the center of a circle represented by a 512x2 matrix using QR Decomposition instead of using least-square in matlab and I am confused on how to go from A=QR to finding a point in the middle of a circle. They call finding the center,raidus and RMS error "fitting the circle"

Comment: Maybe more suitable to Math SE? https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Mmmm are you sure you know what you are doing? QR is a method for decomposing A, commonly used to solve the least squares minimization. Your *instead of* confuses me.